# printer interfacing with JSP

Tags: jsp, printing, applet

Am working on a hotel management web application. My problem is regarding the bill printing.
I have used window.print() for printing the bill. But it causes alignment problems in multiple page printing. Our client is using a dot matrix printer. Is it possible to do it with printer settings, i prefer to use applet. If it is not possible I can use a report like Jreport . Can anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Jasper` or Java (iText) `PDF` API that generate PDF documents at server side and later allow your client to *download* or *print* them.